# Can Singapore ban me because I left a contract position on short notice?

Tags: filipino-citizens, singapore, working-visas, visa-bans

I worked in Singapore as a healthcare assistant in a hospital starting in 2001. I was an overseas Filipino worker. My contract should have been  until 2005 but I went home in 2004 for an emergency regarding an ill relative, and never came back to work again. I was asked to pay because of a short notice: it's like a resignation, but didn't.

Am I blacklisted? can I still work for another job in the future or go to Singapore as a tourist?

Answer (score 3):

**No**, you are not blacklisted. Bans are for immigration offences, not employment disputes.  As long as you left before the expiry of your visa and settled all your taxes, you're fine as far as the government is concerned.

That said, Singapore *does* allow the practice of payment in lieu of notice, including compensation for breaches, so it's theoretically possible that you would be sued for this.  Few companies would find it worth the effort though, and this would in any case be a civil suit, not criminal.

[https://www.mom.gov.sg/employment-practices/termination-of-employment/termination-without-notice#:~:text=If%20you%20resign%20without%20giving,salary%20in%20lieu%20of%20notice.&text=You%20can%20do%20so%20by,during%20the%20required%20notice%20period](https://www.mom.gov.sg/employment-practices/termination-of-employment/termination-without-notice#:%7E:text=If%20you%20resign%20without%20giving,salary%20in%20lieu%20of%20notice.&text=You%20can%20do%20so%20by,during%20the%20required%20notice%20period).